# How to bind rows in R such that instead of type conversion error binding defaults to filling value to NA?

Tags: r, dplyr, bind, rows, na

I am currently tasked with merging multiple xlsx files into one master R (.rds) data file. Since these files are filled in manually there is a lot type conversion errors when using approaches such as dyplr::bind_rows such as

``` Column ``XYZ`` can't be converted from numeric to character ```

While I very much need the binding to be "smart" such that it happens according to the corresponding column names of the to be merged dataframes -when encountering conversion issues instead of getting an error, I would like to have these problematic cell contents treated as NA and not get an error - just a warning perhaps.

Is there a convenient way/function for doing this in R?

I have used bind_rows from dyplr package.

My current import procedure

```
files  <- list.files("data",pattern = "xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

tmp <- read_excel(files[1], sheet = "data", trim_ws = TRUE)
names(tmp) <- make.names(str_squish(names(tmp)))

for (i in 2:length(files)) {
  print(i)
  tmp2 <- read_excel(files[i], sheet = "data",trim_ws = TRUE)
  names(tmp2) <- make.names(str_squish(names(tmp2)))

  tmp<-bind_rows(tmp,tmp2)
}
```

It has been pointed out that using a loop here is not efficient, but since the files are messy - many manual mistakes - and relatively small in number I focused on being able to sequentially track the binding process.

Comment: You should not be using `bind_rows` in a loop which can lead to quadractic copying; `bind_rows` can take a list of data frames to append all elements **once**. Are all Excel files the same format? If so, possibly missing values cause type issues. Try use *col_types* arg in `read_excel`.

Comment: I understand the concern regarding the loop, but it's a limited number of files (n<20, cell dimension are around 4x90) and this way I could seq. track where the type conversion errors where coming from.

I have good understanding of the errors: some students accidently format the cells as char instead of numeric, use commas instead of dots or add the metric unit in text within the cells, mistype the dates in date cells etc. Regardless I would simply like the type conversion to default to NA - instead of algorithmically treating all error cases.

Comment: *I would like to have these problematic cell contents treated as NA* ... you need to iterate through every row of every column and attempt a type conversion of values. On fail, convert single value to NA and then entire column (i.e., vector) to desired type.

Comment: I understand - I guess I was just wondering whether there is an already existing implementation of this. It seems useful to me to be able to default to some value when encountering type conversion errors.